Linear Program Optimal Value
If $f(A,b,c)$ is the optimal value of a linear program
$\min c.x$
subject to $A.x \leq b ; x \geq 0.$
Does $f(A,b,c)$ have a piecewise polynomial/rational upper bound in $(A,b,c)$ on the domain of points in which the optimal value is well-defined/finite? Here, we assume that the matrix $A$ is an $m \times n$ matrix.

Not sure if this is correct, but isn't this answered by "Hoffmann constants"?

@Dirk Perhaps a math textbook reference or theorem would be good. Please feel free to share any formal argument for a proof regarding the above mathematical statement.

That's not really my area of math… However, I think that Hoffmann constants are not the right thing to look at. You may find some (local) results under "sensitivity analysis of LPs", though.
